# PayPal IPN theory and method

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

I've built a buy/sell/trade site, Its not launched yet but before I do launch I need to add in a PayPal IPN feature so users have to pay a small fee before their advert goes live!

But I've never used paypal IPN before and all the tutorials I can find are for things like premium memberships... So quite how I implement this is a bit 'messy' if you see what I mean.

You can view the site at http://www.airgunvillage.com/ if you wish. Like I said its still pre launch but I'm planning to put the first 500 users who advertise into a draw for a prize, at the half way point I want to turn on this paypal IPN so that it covers the cost... (hence I need it done now, not after launch)

My thoughts are I have 2 ways to do this:

**Method 1**
i use paypal IPN to update a 'paid' column in the adverts after advert has been uploaded by user.

PROBLEM: I'm going to have my advert table cluttered with adverts people have not paid for - I'm going to have my image folder with images that do not belong to live adverts.

GOOD: I can upload and go to a preview page then pay for the advert which would let people see what they are getting I suppose.

I suppose I could write a function to clear out unpaid adverts after 1 week or something...

**Method 2**
Advertise form sends all data through to paypal IPN listener, upon a successful payment data is uploaded.

PROBLEM: How to validate form, then send data to paypal. almost need two submits?

GOOD: No junk images, no junk advert DB files.

What would you do? and why?

many thanks :)

Comment: 1. with a nightly cron  script that just cleans up the unpaid submissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with Method 1. Writing a script to keep your tables/images clean should be trivially easy.

with Method 2, I'd question whether PayPal would pass all that data around for you. Method 1 is much cleaner.

Another option would be to store unpaid ads in a temporary table that mirrors the paid for one. You could use the temporary table for previews and such. When the IPN POST comes in, just copy data from temporary holding table to the live table. Then, as with method 1, run a cron job every few days to clear up old/unpaid items.

Comment: I guess I am just getting lazy in the final stages, method 1 is a little more work but it works better, ill get cracking :)